# Emscripten: emmake generating .js files

Tags: javascript, c++, emscripten

According to the [Emscripten Docs](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/compiling/Building-Projects.html)

> Make generates linked LLVM bitcode. It does not automatically generate JavaScript during linking because all the files must be compiled using the same optimizations and compiler options — and it makes sense to do this in the final conversion from bitcode to JavaScript.

Which is great and what I want to do. However, running Emscripten to compile the [openjpeg .jp2 library](https://github.com/uclouvain/openjpeg) generates 4 uncompressed (`-O0`) .js files in the 5-6mb range, and three identical bytecode `.so` files of 514kb, which don't seem to contain the code I need. When I run them through `emcc` they come out as 141kb, without a `_main` function or anything recognizable, and don't behave the same as the other `.js` files.

**What do I need to change to generate correct bytecode with the `emmake` command rather than .js files?**

`emcmake cmake` completes ok and then `emmake make` works, but I don't have the option to try various optimizations or any of the options `emcc` would normally give.

I'm attempting this compilation on Lubuntu 15.04 in a vbox under Win 8. This is my first emscripten project other than the tutorials. I'm also not very familiar with c or c++ or compilation in general (though I can compile this project into Linux applications with no problems).

I'm aware of [j2k.js](https://github.com/kripken/j2k.js), but I'm looking for obj_compress, not obj_decompress.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the usage of emcmake or emmake directly but worked on a CMAKE based C++ project, a main executable, that used be compiled to an x86_64 executable on linux, and that I converted to emscriptem in order to deploy it on an Nginx server.

### CMAKE cross compilation + target platform and ouput = Toolchain File + linker flags + compiler flags

openjpeg.jp2 project is a CMAKE C/C++ program.

Here you are trying to cross compile a C/C++ lib or executable from your **host** **linux** **x86** with **GCC** for instance, could also be **Windows** + **Visual** **C++ compiler.**

#### Toolchain file

You need a **CMAKE toolchain file** that's gonna tell CMAKE how to use emscriptem tools including the emscriptem compiler, and linker that produce JS or WebAssembly.

- Get an Emscriptem cmake toolchain file example here linux GCC x86:
  https://gist.github.com/romatou18/9f631147b5b26f980ab9669c375a6e3f

#### Compiler flags

- When using a CMAKE project refer to the CMakeLists.txt file in order to find/apply/modify the compiler and linker flags based on debug/release build types selected i.e. the GCC build flag for the openjpeg.jp2 project:

example of compiler flags:
https://github.com/uclouvain/openjpeg/blob/172c8ae5cf230ff74b5814daf29e5b577aa30a9b/CMakeLists.txt#L200

Again I do not know the specifics of emmake/emcmake but if your project is CMAKE based, the toolchain file should tell CMAKE all that it needs to know to compile your program.

#### Emscriptem Linker flags : choose Native JS or WebAssembly output

CMakelists.txt that specifies emscriptem linker flags and selects either JS or WebAssembly as an output based on the **JS_ONLY** option:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
message( "Current dir: ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}" )

#make sure it is all static
SET(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ".a")
SET(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARIES OFF)

option(JS_ONLY "Compiles to native JS (No WASM)" OFF)

add_executable( myProgram main.cpp)
target_link_libraries( myProgram ${API_LIB})
target_compile_features(myProgram PRIVATE cxx_std_14)


if(JS_ONLY)
  message(STATUS "Setting compilation target to native JavaScript")
  set(CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX ".js")
  set_target_properties(myProgram PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "--emrun -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS='[_main]'")
else(JS_ONLY)
  message(STATUS "Setting compilation target to WASM")
  set(CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX ".wasm.js")
  set_target_properties(myProgram PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "--emrun -s WASM=1 -s BINARYEN_METHOD='native-wasm' -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS='[_main]' -s NO_EXIT_RUNTIME=1 -s EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS=['ccall']")
endif(JS_ONLY)

#- Compiling to emscriptem/js output: PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS set to --emrun -s 

#- Compiling to emscriptem/WASM => webAssembly output: PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS set to --emrun -s WASM=1 -s BINARYEN_METHOD='native-wasm'
```

**Note**
WebAssembly is the lowest output level you will get with EmscriptEm, should be a more compact that JS in theory.

### Customising the Cmakelist.txt

On this specific project, reuse the example CMakeLists.txt i gave above and customise it:

- Setup your emscriptem target like mentioned above with the link flag on the emscriptem target

```
set_target_properties(... PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "--emrun -s <emscript em link flags as described above>)
```

- Configure release build compiler flags for the release build C AND OR C++ depending on the source language(s) of the project, C flags example below:

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "-O0 -ggdb -Wall -Wunused-variable -Wno-unused-parameter -fno-inline ... etc ...etc ...")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O2 -Wno-format-security -Wno-format-nonliteral -Wall -Wunused-variable -Wno-unused-parameter")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} [+ optional extra flags for both here...]"
```

### Running the cmake config

Now is the time to use the toolchain file:

- Run cmake using the desired build type and specify the toolchain file that tells CMAKE how to use emscriptem, TAKEN from the gist above:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:string="Release" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=Toolchain-Emscripten.cmake src/"
```

Replace the src/ by the source directory.

I have not tried running this on the openjpeg project but I think this should put your on the right track. Iterate on this until it work. I have a working lib and exec using exactly this, no more ;-)

Again this is a CMAKE based project it looks nicely designed and looks modular, therefore I would stick with using CMAKE + cross compilation toolchain file and leave the details of make/emmake to ... CMAKE, unless you really have no other choice.

Hope this helps!

Romain